# Moving Actor using TouchDown event in Scene2d

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm looking for a way to move an Actor when it is touched. I've tried the code below. However, related Actor lacks to support touchdown event, so I'm getting a **NullPointerException**.

```
actor.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)     {
        event.getRelatedActor().addAction(moveBy(0,10,0.5f));
            return true;
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`getTarget()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Event.html#getTarget%28%29) to get the Actor the event originated from.

The `getRelatedActor()` method is for events that involve two actors (like focus change or enter/exit events).  This isn't particularly clear in the doc, but if you look at the [FocusEvent](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/FocusListener.FocusEvent.html) doc for `getRelatedActor` you'll see how its used there.